# Not able to match the RegExp in JavaScript even it is matching in QuickRex

Tags: javascript

Not able to match the regular expression in my JavaScript code which I have written for form validation.

I wanted to validate my form field which is password using RegExp [[0-9]{0,8}[a-z]{0,8}[A-Z]{1,8}@]

My Validations on password is
- Should contain 10 characters including digit
- At least one uppercase letter should be there
- Only @ should be used as special character

But the same is working with [0-9a-zA-Z@]{10} but not with [[0-9]{0,8}[a-z]{0,8}[A-Z]{1,8}@]

```
var regexpassword=/[[0-9]{0,8}[a-z]{0,8}[A-Z]{1,8}@]/
if(!regexpassword.test(password.value)){
    alert("Enter valid password")
    password.focus();
    return false
}
```

NOTE: The password that I have entered is Welcome@67

It should not give the alert as "Enter valid password"

Comment: You can't "nest" `[ ]` inside another `[ ]`

Comment: You can try using an online RegEx tester like https://regex101.com/ to see what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can tell, the regex you provided, is matching exactly 1 character.  the [] operator indicates "any of what is inside".  But the only place you are indicating "multiple times" is the [A-Z]{1,8}.  Also, as @Pointy mentioned, I don't think you can nest square brackets.  Even if you can, it is somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 0):

[Your regex is being interpreted as follows](https://regex101.com/r/FI9I37/1):
1. Look for `[` or the numbers 0 through 9 between 0 and 8 times in a row
2. Followed precisely by the lowercase letters `a` through `z` between 0 and 8 times in a row
3. Followed precisely by the uppercase letters `A` through `Z` between 1 and 8 times in a row
4. Followed precisely by a single `@`
5. Followed precisely by a single `]`

This leads to matching strings like (but not limited to):

```
[A@]
0A@]
9aaaaaaaZ@]
[0123456abcdefghABCDEFGH@]
[[[[[[[[Q@]
[[[[[[[[azazazazAZAZAZAZ@]
```

but it will not match `Welcome@67`.

Is there a way to write a regex that will validate a password with your requirements?
Possibly.

Should you use a *single* regex to validate your password?
Probably not as the necessary complexity of that regex would make it impractical to maintain when your password requirements change.

Is there a practical, maintainable way to validate passwords?
Certainly! Use multiple regexes to validate the required parts of the password.
Then determine if the needed parts are present and make sure the length is acceptable.

Example:

```js
var hasOnlyValidCharacters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z@]+$/gm.test(password.value);
var hasDigits = /[0-9]+/gm.test(password.value);
var hasUpper = /[A-Z]+/gm.test(password.value);
var hasLower = /[a-z]+/gm.test(password.value);
var hasAtSign = /[@]+/gm.test(password.value); // Technically could be /@+/gm.test(...), but I tend to use character classes every time I'm looking for specific characters.

var isValidPassword = (
    password.value.length === 10    // Should contain 10 characters
    && hasOnlyValidCharacters
    && hasDigits                    // including digit
    && hasUpper                     // At least one uppercase letter should be there
//     && hasLower                  // Uncomment to require at least one lowercase letter
//     && hasAtSign                 // Uncomment to require at least one @
);

if (!isValidPassword) {
    alert("Enter valid password")
    password.focus();
    return false
}
```

The [untested code] above *should* do the trick, and following the patterns established in it, you should be able to easily change your password requirements on a whim.